# In WordPress how can I restrict access to xmlprc to specific ip/host

Tags: wordpress, api, xml-rpc

I have a WordPress site on my server. I'm developing an application, hosted on the same server, that integrate with WordPress through xml-rpc (in this moment I can't use Rest API) managing posts, taxonomies and so on.

How can I restrict access to xmlrpc service only to my application/server?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on Apache server you can just write a rule in the server configuration file to only allow access from your IP address, something like this:

```
# Deny the access of xmlrpc.php
<FilesMatch "xmlrpc\.php">
        order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 192.168.1.2
</FilesMatch>
```